# Downloading a image using Python Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to write a Python script to download a image and set it as my wallpaper. Unfortunately, the Mechanize documentation is quite poor. My script is following the link correctly, but I'm having a hard time to actually save the image on my computer. From what I researched, the .retrieve() method should do the work, but How do I specify the path to where the file should be downloaded to? Here is what I have...

```
def followLink(browser, fixedLink):
    browser.open(fixedLink)

if browser.find_link(url_regex = r'1600x1200'):

    browser.follow_link(url_regex = r'1600x1200')

elif browser.find_link(url_regex = r'1400x1050'):

    browser.follow_link(url_regex = r'1400x1050')

elif browser.find_link(url_regex = r'1280x960'):

    browser.follow_link(url_regex = r'1280x960')

 return
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import mechanize, os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

browser = mechanize.Browser()
html = browser.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
image_tags = soup.findAll('img')
for image in image_tags:
    filename = image['src'].lstrip('http://')
    filename = os.path.join(dir, filename.replace('/', '_'))
    data = browser.open(image['src']).read()
    browser.back()
    save = open(filename, 'wb')
    save.write(data)
    save.close()
```

This can help you download all the images from a web page. As for parsing html you'd better use BeautifulSoup or lxml. And download is just read the data and then write it to a local file. You should assign your own value to dir. It is where you images exist.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why this solution hasn't come up, but you can use the `mechanize.Browser.retrieve` function as well. Perhaps this only works in newer versions of `mechanize` and has thus not been mentioned?

Anyway, if you wanted to shorten [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15594661/476371) by [zhangyangyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189957), you could do this:

```
import mechanize, os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

browser = mechanize.Browser()
html = browser.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
image_tags = soup.findAll('img')
for image in image_tags:
    filename = image['src'].lstrip('http://')
    filename = os.path.join(dir, filename.replace('/', '_'))
    browser.retrieve(image['src'], filename)
    browser.back()
```

Also keep in mind that you'll likely want to put all of this into a `try` `except` block like this one:

```
import mechanize, os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

browser = mechanize.Browser()
html = browser.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
image_tags = soup.findAll('img')
for image in image_tags:
    filename = image['src'].lstrip('http://')
    filename = os.path.join(dir, filename.replace('/', '_'))
    try:
        browser.retrieve(image['src'], filename)
        browser.back()
    except (mechanize.HTTPError,mechanize.URLError) as e:
        pass
        # Use e.code and e.read() with HTTPError
        # Use e.reason.args with URLError
```

Of course you'll want to adjust this to your needs. Perhaps you want it to bomb out if it encounters an issue. It totally depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You can get/download the image by opening the url of the img src.

```
image_response = browser.open_novisit(img['src'])
```

to save the file now, just use fopen:

```
with open('image_out.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(image_response.read())
```

Comment: it is not working. I get the error: "NameError: global name 'img' is not defined". And where the image was supposed to be saved?

Comment: here in the first line "img" means it's looking for the "<img>" tag. Point it to the tag which contains the url of the image you want to save in its "src" attribute.  Also, the image will be saved in the same folder as the script, as shown in the f.write statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's really crappy but It "works" for me, with [0xc0000022l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476371/0xc0000022l) anwer's

import mechanize, os
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib2

```
def DownloadIMGs(url): # IMPORTANT URL WITH HTTP OR HTTPS
    print "From", url
    dir = 'F:\Downloadss' #Dir for Downloads
    basicImgFileTypes = ['png','bmp','cur','ico','gif','jpg','jpeg','psd','raw','tif']

    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    html = browser.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    image_tags = soup.findAll('img')
    print "N Images:", len(image_tags)
    print
    #---------SAVE PATH
    #check if available
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)
    #---------SAVE PATH
    for image in image_tags:

        #---------SAVE PATH + FILENAME (Where It is downloading)
        filename = image['src']
        fileExt = filename.split('.')[-1]
        fileExt = fileExt[0:3]

        if (fileExt in basicImgFileTypes):
            print 'File Extension:', fileExt
            filename = filename.replace('?', '_')
            filename = os.path.join(dir, filename.split('/')[-1])
            num = filename.find(fileExt) + len(fileExt)
            filename = filename[:num]
        else:
            filename = filename.replace('?', '_')
            filename = os.path.join(dir, filename.split('/')[-1]) + '.' + basicImgFileTypes[0]
        print 'File Saving:', filename
        #---------SAVE PATH + FILENAME (Where It is downloading)

        #--------- FULL URL PATH OF THE IMG
        imageUrl = image['src']
        print 'IMAGE SRC:', imageUrl

        if (imageUrl.find('http://') > -1 or imageUrl.find('https://') > -1):
            pass
        else:
            if (url.find('http://') > -1):
                imageUrl = url[:len('http://')]
                imageUrl = 'http://' + imageUrl.split('/')[0] + image['src']
            elif(url.find('https://') > -1):
                imageUrl = url[:len('https://')]
                imageUrl = 'https://' + imageUrl.split('/')[0] + image['src']
            else:
                imageUrl = image['src']

        print 'IMAGE URL:', imageUrl
        #--------- FULL URL PATH OF THE IMG

        #--------- TRY DOWNLOAD
        try:
            browser.retrieve(imageUrl, filename)
            print "Downloaded:", image['src'].split('/')[-1]
            print
        except (mechanize.HTTPError,mechanize.URLError) as e:
            print "Can't Download:", image['src'].split('/')[-1]
            print
            pass
        #--------- TRY DOWNLOAD
    browser.close()

DownloadIMGs('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593925/downloading-a-image-using-python-mechanize')
```